# Error sklearn.metrics in titanic kaggle competitionm

Tags: python

I have try Machine Learning project on kaggle. i found code in their forum that posted 1 years ago.

```
from sklearn.metrics import metrics.confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
l = dataset3.iloc[:,0].values

y_pred[1]

sub =[]
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
    if(y_pred[i]==False):
        sub.append(0)
    else:
        sub.append(1)

j = np.asarray(sub)
j.to_csv('ubmission.csv', index=False)
```

and the error code was:

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-2ce1bcbdbc42>", line 78
    from sklearn.metrics import metrics.confusion_matrix
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
invalid syntax (<ipython-input-3-2ce1bcbdbc42>
```

is the sklearn.metric update their syntax or another problem?
thanks before

Comment: what about `from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix`?

Answer (score 1):

Write it as:-

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
```